# Angular giving injector error but still returning variables

Tags: angularjs

So Im sure this is a simple problem im just overlooking, because I have similar functions working in other controllers. But for some reason i am getting this error.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tourinfoProvider <- tourinfo <- PhotoplanCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=tourinfoProvider[object Object]3C-%tourinfo%%3C-%PhotoplanCtrl
```

But the worst part is that its printing out the data for tourinfo! Its actually working, so although its says it has no idea what tourinfo is, its giving me the data. This is my controller code.

```
var app= angular.module('planoxApp')

  app.controller('PhotoplanCtrl',['$http','$scope','$stateParams','$filter','$uibModal','$log',
  'RecieverService','tourinfo',function($http,$scope, $stateParams,$filter,$uibModal,$log,RecieverService,tourinfo){

      var tour = tourinfo
      console.log(tour)
```

Theres obviously more but im chopping it off because it has nothing to with the problem. Heres the route with a resolve that its supposed to get tourinfo from.

```
.state('home.photoplans', {  //the main photoplan pages, with photoplan nav bar
  url: '/photoplans/{id}',
  templateUrl: 'photoplan/photoplanmain.html',
  authenticate: true,
  controller: 'PhotoplanCtrl',
  resolve:{
  tourinfo:function(RecieverService,$stateParams){
    return RecieverService.tourinfo($stateParams.id);
  }
}
```

This is obviously working or else we would never reach the controller or page in the first place. So does anyone see any glaring issues? Im just really confused, i have done this 20 times, and this is the only one giving me problems. I dont know what I have done wrong. I will post additional code if requested.

Heres a plunkr that is not working, though im unsure if its not working due to my code or the fact I have never used plunkr before. Just a warning I had to change some of my code up or else I would be adding 10+ files in order to get everything to run.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2FPlB45XYfvZw7obWD4e?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake is to declare a controller twice.

I.e. you have the controller **PhotoplanCtrl** defined in your route definition:

```
.state('home.photoplans', {  //the main photoplan pages, with photoplan nav bar
  url: '/photoplans/{id}',
  templateUrl: 'photoplan/photoplanmain.html',
  authenticate: true,
  controller: 'PhotoplanCtrl',
  resolve:{
  tourinfo:function(RecieverService,$stateParams){
    return RecieverService.tourinfo($stateParams.id);
  }
}
```

But do you also have it declared in your template (or elsewhere)...?

```
<div ng-controller="PhotoplanCtrl"></div>
```

*Update: The duplicated controller declaration was the issues.*

If that is not the issue another thing to do is confirm that it is not an error with the call to RecieverService.tourinfo in your routes resolve.

Try sticking a breakpoint at that point.

```
resolve:{
  tourinfo:function(RecieverService,$stateParams){
    return RecieverService.tourinfo($stateParams.id);
  }
```

Finally, a minor thing, but you are missing some semicolons:

```
 var tour = tourinfo
 console.log(tour)
```

Comment: So I put a break point here, but it seems that my receiver is being called correctly and everything being resolved, but thank you!

Comment: Also just noticed that you contoller names do not match up PhotoplanEditCtrl & PhotoplanCtrl

Comment: I fixed that, they were not different controllers, its just i was testing to see if this would work on a different controller. Im trying to make the pulnkr but its not going well, so give me a sec

Comment: One more thing. Quite a common mistake is using ng-controller in your view in addition to using the state controller setup....

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the brackets where you put your dependencies

```
var app = angular.module('planoxApp', []);
```

Comment: So this was not the problem, I have my dependencies in a separate file, but thanks!